# how to send a file using multipart data in android

Tags: android, api, http

i was trying to send multi part data to a server, this server is for hosting files for free, but through its api i am not able to host my files through android app
Here is the url of the free file hosting website:-
[file hosting site](https://gofile.io)

Here is my code in android studio:-

```
            File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20190504-WA0001.mp3");
        String url = "https://srv-store1.gofile.io/uploadFile";
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(url);


        MultipartBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(null, file));
        MultipartBody body = bodyBuilder.build();


        RequestBody requestBody = ProgressHelper.withProgress(body, new ProgressUIListener() {


            @Override
            public void onUIProgressStart(long totalBytes) {
                super.onUIProgressStart(totalBytes);
                Log.e("TAG", "onUIProgressStart:" + totalBytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUIProgressChanged(long numBytes, long totalBytes, float percent, float speed) {
                Log.e("TAG", "=============start===============");
                Log.e("TAG", "numBytes:" + numBytes);
                Log.e("TAG", "totalBytes:" + totalBytes);
                Log.e("TAG", "percent:" + percent);
                Log.e("TAG", "speed:" + speed);
                Log.e("TAG", "============= end ===============");
              

            }


            @Override
            public void onUIProgressFinish() {
                super.onUIProgressFinish();
                Log.e("TAG", "onUIProgressFinish:");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "结束上传", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        
        builder.post(requestBody);

        okhttp3.Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(builder.build());

        call.enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "=============onFailure===============");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.e("TAG", "=============onResponse===============");
                Log.e("TAG", "request headers:" + response.request().headers());
                Log.e("TAG", "response headers:" + response.body().string());
            }
        });
```

and for this the library used in android is:-"implementation '**io.github.lizhangqu:coreprogress:1.0.2**'"

so when i run this code this error occurs:-**Unsupported content type: multipart/mixed;**

I am not getting any clue how to solve this all even after looking at a loads of stackoverflow answers and trying out by nyself.

Comment: Please give a link to gofile api information.

Comment: You could set a different content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found my solution with below code, hope it may help others.

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    int serverResponseCode=0;
    String fileName="/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20190504-WA0001.mp3";
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "------hellojosh";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    Log.e("appTag", "Uploading: sourcefileURI, "+fileName);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+appSingleton.getInstance().photouri);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :");
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        try{

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL("https://srv-store4.gofile.io/uploadFile");
            Log.v("appTag",url.toString());

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Log.i("appTag","->");
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage().toString();
            Log.i("appTag", "HTTP Response is : "  + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            DataInputStream inStream;
            try {
                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                String str;
                while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("appTag", "SOF Server Response" + str);
                }
                inStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("appTag", "SOF error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }

            //close the streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                //Do something
            }
            //END IF Response code 200

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        //END TRY - FILE READ
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("appTag", "UL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        //CATCH - URL Exception

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "+ e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        //after try
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
    //END ELSE, if file exists.
}
```

Although I needed to comment out some things in this code, but this was the best answer for me, I also arranged a code for downloading the file from the server using Android Download Manager, but that is irrevelant of this question.